# The plot’s title and legend are not responsive within shiny context

Tags: html, r, shiny

As shown in the image below, despite using FluidRow, the title as well as the legend for my plot within shiny context are not responsive. How can I fix this?
Best,
Nader[image]

Comment: What do you mean by fluid a ggtitle? Can you provide a reproducible example with output?

Comment: I I have developed a shiny app which uses FluidRow to fluid the plot in a row. When I resize the page, the plot in that row is resized but the plot’s title remains unchanged. Given that the title for the plot is part of the row, I am expecting the title also to be responsive; but this is not the case.